# gridview_paging messing up

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging

I have an asp.net C# web app. In it I have a gridview. The gridview gets search results from a database. Sometimes there are a lot of results, and so I wanted to use paging. Here's what I tried:

```
     protected void grdResults_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        grdResults.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        grdResults.DataBind();
    }
```

For some reason, when I click on a page number, it shows me the EmptyDataText(There are no records to display). What code would work?
Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning the datasource in NeedDataSource event.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reassign your datasource to grdResults before the call to DataBind().

Comment: Only if it isn't already declared in markup or in, say, a Load event.  Do you have ViewState disabled?  If not, I don't think you'd need to re-databind unless your data source only contains the displayed records (and omits the ones on other pages).

Comment: You're right. I don't need to rebind the data. But now, it doesnt change the the page until I click the page number twice...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code It will absoloutly work :

```
protected void GV_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{

    GV.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindGrid();
}

    public override void BindGrid()
{
    query = new CommonQueries();
    GV.DataSource = query.getAllBooks();
    GV.DataBind();
}
```

the problem with your code is that you did'nt reassign the data source to your gridview !